# Error in Json Android

Tags: android, json

When i call an webservice i receive response in json format.The app works fine but when I receive json like `{ "NewDataSet": }}` my app runs into catch statement and I m getting error like this - `org.json.JSONException: Expected literal value at character 16 of { "NewDataSet": }}`

Code to parse json

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute (s);

            try {
//                jsonObject = new JSONObject (s);
                String response=s.trim ();
                jsonObject = new JSONObject (response);
                if (NewDataSet == null) {
                    Toast.makeText (Login.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
                }
                NewDataSet = jsonObject.getJSONObject ("NewDataSet");
                Table = NewDataSet.getJSONObject ("Table");
                String User_ID = Table.getString ("User_ID");
                String Vendor_IEntity_Code = Table.getString ("Vendor_IEntity_Code");
                String Vendor_Name = Table.getString ("Vendor_Name");

                SettingPreference.setUserId (Login.this, User_ID);
                SettingPreference.setVendorId (Login.this, Vendor_IEntity_Code);
                SettingPreference.setVendorName (Login.this, Vendor_Name);

                Log.e ("Json response", "" + User_ID + "" + Vendor_IEntity_Code + "" + Vendor_Name);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
```

Comment: can you post the whole JSON you recieved? and you can validate your JSON response using http://pro.jsonlint.org/

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: that is not a valid JSON. it is supposed to throw exception.

Comment: means i will get an error?? or else how to parse it cos when NewDataSet = blanks this means user is not authenticated

Comment: Use GSON instead of JSONParser.

Comment: i dont know how to use it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is simply not valid. You need to assign a value to 'NewDataSet'. If you want this to be empty you can set the value to an empty String like ""

```
{ "NewDataSet": ""}
```

to retrieve this data you can use:

```
String result = jsonObject.getString("NewDataSet");
```

Comment: {"success":"0"}
I have this json nw how do i parse it to get the value of success

Comment: @user3667909 I have edited my answer. Note that you can also put integers in json objects: `{"success":0}` and retrieve it with `jsonObject.getInt("success");`